# CORS issue on Localhost, MULTIPLE workarounds have failed

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, localhost

**I am in tears as I type this, sobbing into my keyboard**

I have wasted over a week trying to understand what is wrong. I can no longer learn or develop. I am going to have to give up learning to code if I cannot fix this.

I understand what CORS is. If I had the ability to edit the API server, I would, but I do not. I **must** use a 3rd party API. I do not have the time to develop my own to work with. I am **UNABLE** to develop using anything but a local server. I need to stop CORS issues.

I have been trying to fix this problem for days. I am at a complete standstill with my learning. A week of tears and frustratiion has ben spent on this.

**I CANNOT:**

- use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com. This fails and CORS still screams:

  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
- Develop non-locally
- Proxy. Package.json just ignores it. I have made **multiple** attempts to use proxying to avoid CORS. All attempts have ended in complete failure.

I legitimately do not know what to do. This is my code. Please help me, I am in tears and I cannot learn React anymore until this is fixed.

```js
import axios from "axios";

let getFriends = () => {
  const config = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10",
    crossdomain: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  };
  return axios(config);
};

export { getFriends };
```

Comment: Why send a `Content-Type` header with a `GET` request? 1. That makes no sense. 2. With a value of `application/json`, CORS preflight is going to kick in.

Comment: Also, can you share the actual API URL you're trying to hit?

Comment: https://randomuser.me || because that's what my apparently-wrong source for teaching told me to do. I'm beginning to realize it's worthless.

Comment: The error message mentions credentials, but your Axios code snippet doesn't send credentials. Are you telling us everything?

Comment: That `https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10` endpoint appears to be correctly configured for CORS, but doesn't seem to allow credentials. Stop sending a `Content-Type` header with your `GET` request, and don't send a credentialed request.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are going crazy trying to find a solution is because there is nothing YOU can do about CORS. Changing any header as the other solution recommends won't work, the server will still flag any origins which it does not allow calls from!

This is a value controlled by the SERVER whose API you are calling. And, as the error says, the server you are calling *does not accept connections from localhost:3000*.

As long as you are making requests from a browser that is on `localhost:3000` to this API, you'll be hit with CORS issues.

If you want to ensure that the API itself is not broken, use a different tool like Postman to call to the API. This is like a 'server to server' call, and as such does not require CORS checks.

EDIT: The following call to the random user API seems to work:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  const fetchRandomUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10")
    const json = await response.json()
    json.results.forEach((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
  }

  // On mount, fetch random users
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRandomUsers()
  }, [])

  return (
    <></>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Postman runs it just fine.
So am I to understand that I am just forced to be finished learning React, and I cannot learn APIs with React at all whatsoever? That seems like a massive issue for students.

Comment: Please state what API you are using

Comment: https://randomuser.me

Comment: I just edited my answer with a code example. I just used the built-in `fetch` function instead of `axios` and it's working fine from localhost:3000 (I assume axios would work just the same). But I see somehow Heroku is involved? Are you deploying the site there?